# My program will only recognize the file if I specify the entire path

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\harch\pythonstuff\pokemon_data.csv")
dfx = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\harch\pythonstuff\pokemon_data.xlsx")
```

If I use only the file name ('pokemon_data.csv,xlsx) instead of the entire path, I get a 'file does not exist' error even though the data file is in the same directory as the python file. Is specifying the entire path required?

Comment: It isn't necessarily required, but relative file paths are based on the current working directory, not the file location where you make function calls. The answer provided below will get you the result you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the directory path in run time and go to the file from there

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), 'pokemon_data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```